One click unsubscribe does not work while using SES
I am currently trying to implement One-click unsubscribe in my mailing system that uses SES. I have added headers and use my email in ses for sending. At the beginning it worked but then I set custom from domain and it stopped working and even when I remove this custom domain for my identity in ses, unbsubscribe button is still missed.
List-Unsubscribe: https://api/mailing/unsubscribe?token=eyJhb
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
I was trying to set up dmarc, spf for my custom from domain but it does not help maybe I missing some more configuration.
spf "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all"
txt _dmarc.email.mydomain.com

